# Route Parameters in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I know how to use regular expression on route constraints but I want to use use fixed value instead of regular expression like this :

```
Route::get('{param}/delete/{id}',array(
    'as'    => 'delete-post',
    'uses'  => 'MainController@delete'
))->where(['param',['post','page'],'id'=>'[0-9]+']);
```

When I try this , i get the error like 
 `Routing requirement for "param" must be a string.`

What I want is the value of `param` parameter is to be fixed and it should be either `post` or `page` . So, how can I achieve like above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex aswell:

```
Route::get('{param}/delete/{id}',array(
    'as'    => 'delete-post',
    'uses'  => 'MainController@delete'
))->where(['param' => 'post|page', 'id'=>'[0-9]+']);
```